# Change table name in linked table in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to change the name of a table in Access. I've gone to the link manager and gone through that process. It will change to the Server I put it, but it never changes the Table name (Highlighted in yellow).

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems your goal is to change the linked `TableDef`'s `SourceTableName`, but I doubt that is possible.  Attempting to do it triggers error #3268:

> Cannot set this property once the object is part of a collection.

So I think you will have to create a new linked `TableDef` with the `Connect` property from the old link and your new `SourceTableName` value and `Append` that to the `TableDefs` collection.

```vb
Const cstrOldName As String = "dbo_tblFoo2"
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdfOld As DAO.TableDef
Dim tdfNew As DAO.TableDef
Set db = CurrentDb
Set tdfOld = db.TableDefs(cstrOldName)
tdfOld.Name = cstrOldName & "_old" ' rename the old link

Set tdfNew = db.CreateTableDef
With tdfNew
    .Name = cstrOldName
    .Connect = tdfOld.Connect
    .SourceTableName = "dbo.Dual"
End With
db.TableDefs.Append tdfNew
```

Comment: ... or just do it manually in the UI by deleting the old ODBC linked table, creating the new one, and then renaming the new one to have the same name as the old one.

Comment: Can it be done via the UI without a DSN?  I don't see how.

Comment: Sort of. If the new ODBC linked table is created with a *File DSN* (as happens when you click the ["New..." button](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FJm99.png) in the Select Data Source dialog) then the `.Connect` property uses the file's name as `Description` and includes the other connection string elements, too: `ODBC;Description=zzzTestFileDsn;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2010;DATABASE=myDb`.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me.