# Why does this vba table relink code result in error 3219?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, linked-tables

I'm trying to relink tables in an MS Access database separate from the one the code below runs in; this way I can use the repairing db as "patch" of sorts...

I've modified the code I found [here](https://improvingsoftware.com/2009/10/15/code-snippet-quickly-link-sql-server-tables-in-access/), so that it relinks the tables in a database opened by the "repairing / patch database"

Before I run the code I make sure both databases are open so that one can repair the other to make it easier to automate the application of the fix.

However when I run the code, when I get to the line reads `tdfLinked.RefeshLink`, which refreshes the linked table, I get an `Runtime error '3219' Invalid Operation` error.

```
Sub FixDB()

    Call LinkTable("somelinkedTble", "SOMESERVER\NAMED_SQL_INST32", "Database1", "Some_Schema.somelinkedTble", True)

End Sub

Function LinkTable(LinkedTableAlias As String, Server As String, database As String, SourceTableName As String, OverwriteIfExists As Boolean)
    'This method will also update the link if the underlying table definition has been modified.

    'The overwrite parameter will cause it to re-map/refresh the link for LinktedTable Alias, but only if it was already a linked table.
    ' it will not overwrite an existing query or local table with the name specified in LinkedTableAlias.

    ' Begin: Bit that I modified to access the database that needs fixed.
    Dim objAccess As Access.application
    Dim loginInfo As New AuthInfoz

    loginInfo.workgroup = "E:\Tickets\Fix\SEC\Secured.mdw"
    loginInfo.username = "someuser"
    loginInfo.password = "********"
    loginInfo.dbs = "E:\Tickets\Fix\Report.mdb"

    Set objAccess = GetObject(loginInfo.dbs).application

    'Links to a SQL Server table without the need to set up a DSN in the ODBC Console.
    Dim dbsCurrent As database
    Dim tdfLinked As TableDef

    ' Open a database to which a linked table can be appended.
    Set dbsCurrent = objAccess.CurrentDb

    ' END: Bit that I modified to access the external database.

    'Check for and deal with the scenario ofthe table alias already existing
    If TableNameInUse(LinkedTableAlias) Then

        If (Not OverwriteIfExists) Then
            Debug.Print "Can't use name '" + LinkedTableAlias + "' because it would overwrite existing table."
            Exit Function
        End If

        'delete existing table, but only if it is a linked table
        If IsLinkedTable(LinkedTableAlias) Then
            dbsCurrent.TableDefs.Delete LinkedTableAlias
            dbsCurrent.TableDefs.Refresh
        Else
            Debug.Print "Can't use name '" + LinkedTableAlias + "' because it would overwrite an existing query or local table."
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

    'Create a linked table
    Set tdfLinked = dbsCurrent.CreateTableDef(LinkedTableAlias)
    tdfLinked.SourceTableName = SourceTableName
    tdfLinked.Connect = "ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=" & Server & ";DATABASE=" & database & ";TRUSTED_CONNECTION=yes;"

    On Error Resume Next
    dbsCurrent.TableDefs.Append tdfLinked
    If (Err.Number = 3626) Then 'too many indexes on source table for Access
            Err.Clear
            On Error GoTo 0

            If LinkTable(LinkedTableAlias, Server, database, "vw" & SourceTableName, OverwriteIfExists) Then
                Debug.Print "Can't link directly to table '" + SourceTableName + "' because it contains too many indexes for Access to handle. Linked to view '" & "vw" & SourceTableName & "' instead."
                LinkTable = True
            Else
                Debug.Print "Can't link table '" + SourceTableName + "' because it contains too many indexes for Access to handle. Create a view named '" & "vw" & SourceTableName & "' that selects all rows/columns from '" & SourceTableName & "' and try again to circumvent this."
                LinkTable = False
            End If
            Exit Function
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    tdfLinked.RefreshLink
    LinkTable = True

End Function

Function BuildSQLConnectionString(Server As String, DBName As String) As String
    BuildSQLConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server & ";Database=" & DBName & ";TRUSTED_CONNECTION=yes;"
End Function

Function TableNameInUse(TableName As String) As Boolean
    'check for local tables, linked tables and queries (they all share the same namespace)
    TableNameInUse = DCount("*", "MSYSObjects", "(Type = 4 or type=1 or type=5) AND [Name]='" & TableName & "'") > 0
End Function

Function IsLinkedTable(TableName As String) As Boolean
    IsLinkedTable = DCount("*", "MSYSObjects", "(Type = 4) AND [Name]='" & TableName & "'") > 0
End Function
```

Comment: If `tdfLinked` is newly created, why would you even want to do `tdfLinked.RefreshLink`?

Comment: Oh, that's because it already exists.  I'm re-linking it.

Comment: You are overcomplicating this. There is no reason to delete the linked table, just set the new/revised Connect and do a RefreshLink.

Comment: Maybe I misread your code, but it looks to me like you're deleting the link and then recreating it (`CreateTableDef`) with the updated connection information.  If you just change the `.Connect` property of an existing link, as Gustav suggested, then you would call `RefreshLink` to signal Access that it needs to update the metadata it stores about the linked table.

Comment: Try, this out. CurrentDB.TableDefs(TableName).RefreshLink instead. Also are you sure you are adding the fields with the append?

Comment: @HansUp Thanks!  Your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35802278/18149 combined with the code above seems as though it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proven example you should be able to adopt:

```
Public Function AttachSqlServer( _
    ByVal Hostname As String, _
    ByVal Database As String, _
    ByVal Username As String, _
    ByVal Password As String) _
    As Boolean

' Attach all tables linked via ODBC to SQL Server or Azure SQL.
' 2016-04-24. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

    Const cstrQuery1    As String = "_Template"
    Const cstrQuery2    As String = "_TemplateRead"
    Const cstrQuery3    As String = "VerifyConnection"

    Const cstrDbType    As String = "ODBC"
    Const cstrAcPrefix  As String = "dbo_"

    Dim dbs             As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf             As DAO.TableDef
    Dim strConnect      As String
    Dim strName         As String

    On Error GoTo Err_AttachSqlServer

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    strConnect = ConnectionString(Hostname, Database, Username, Password)

    For Each tdf In dbs.TableDefs
        strName = tdf.Name
        If Asc(strName) <> Asc("~") Then
            If InStr(tdf.Connect, cstrDbType) = 1 Then
                If Left(strName, Len(cstrAcPrefix)) = cstrAcPrefix Then
                    tdf.Name = Mid(strName, Len(cstrAcPrefix) + 1)
                End If
                tdf.Connect = strConnect
                tdf.RefreshLink
                Debug.Print Timer, tdf.Name, tdf.SourceTableName, tdf.Connect
                DoEvents
            End If
        End If
    Next
    dbs.QueryDefs(cstrQuery1).Connect = strConnect
    dbs.QueryDefs(cstrQuery2).Connect = strConnect
    dbs.QueryDefs(cstrQuery3).Connect = strConnect
    Debug.Print "Done!"

    AttachSqlServer = True

Exit_AttachSqlServer:
    Set tdf = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    Exit Function

Err_AttachSqlServer:
    Call ErrorMox
    Resume Exit_AttachSqlServer

End Function
```

Comment: I'm connecting to a database outside the one being relinked.  The above code seems to entail that it's connecting to one locally, where the module being run is inside that `.mdb` file.  The one I'm connecting to does not contain the module, it's being called from a seperate `.mdb`