# ACCESS VBA adding fields Error 3219

Tags: ms-access, vba

i'm trying to add 2 columns to the table "schede" but i always return Error 3219. Can anyone help? Here is the code:

```vb
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb()
'add columns
Dim campo1 As Field
Set campo1 = db.TableDefs("SCHEDE").CreateField("cliente", dbText, 6)
CurrentDb.TableDefs("SCHEDE").Fields.Append (campo1)
Set campo1 = CurrentDb.TableDefs("SCHEDE").CreateField("da_canc", dbText, 3)
CurrentDb.TableDefs("SCHEDE").Fields.Append (campo1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this vba table relink code result in error 3219?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37837817/why-does-this-vba-table-relink-code-result-in-error-3219)

Comment: Any reason for those short text fields (6 and 3 chars max)?

Answer (score 0):

As [Fields.Append](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820791.aspx) is a sub (not a function) you have to pass its arguments without parentheses (or add a`Call`at beginning). Also reuse your database reference (`db`).

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database 'Library name to clearfy reference (e.g ADODB has a database object too)
Set db = CurrentDb()
'add columns
With db.TableDefs("SCHEDE") 'for DRY
    .Fields.Append .CreateField("cliente", dbText, 6)
    .Fields.Append .CreateField("da_canc", dbText, 3)
End With
```